# Intellij isn't catching non-exhaustive matches that use functions as guards

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I found this block of code in our codebase:

```
val appId: (String, Option[String]) = request.app match {
  case Some(app) if hasAppId(app) => (Constants.AppId, app.id)
  case None => (Constants.AppId, None)
}
```

hasAppId returns a boolean. Clearly this match is non-exhaustive, but there's no compiler warning for it. If I change the guard to

```
case Some(app) if false =>
```

I get the expected warning. Why is Intellij failing to detect this non-exhaustive match?

edit: Here's the definition of hasAppId. Note the explicit Boolean return:

```
def hasAppId(app: App): Boolean = app.id.isDefined && !app.id.get.isEmpty
```

Comment: Have you made sure that `hasAppId(app) => (Constants.AppId, app.id)` evaluates to a boolean?

Comment: Updated question with hasAppId definition and match case's type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with IntelliJ, but is simply a limitation of the Scala compiler.

The warning does not appear whenever a nontrivial `if` clause is present.  You can even try this in the REPL:

```
Option(1) match { case Some(x) => ??? } //warning
Option(1) match { case Some(x) if Math.random > 0.5 => ??? } //no warning
```

The reason that you don't get the warning when you write `if false` (or `if 1==1` or other simple expressions) is because of *constant folding* whereby the compiler can remove or combine constants at an earlier stage of the compilation process.

Remember that these are just warnings, and that the compiler cannot be expected to perfectly understand when a match might be exhaustive.  This example is particularly simple, but in more complex examples this logic could be completely nontrivial.  It seems to me that the compiler doesn't even try if there is any `if` statement on the `case`, and that the cases where you are seeing that are purely because of constant folding.

This is mentioned in the language specification is [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-expressions), where it says that the compiler *can* emit a warning:

> If the selector of a pattern match is an instance of a sealed class, the compilation of pattern matching can emit warnings which diagnose that a given set of patterns is not exhaustive, i.e. that there is a possibility of a `MatchError` being raised at run-time.

Comment: That all makes sense. Short of searching our code for lines containing 'case' and 'if' is there a good way to detect this kind of non-exhaustive match?

Answer (score 0):

This will be in the next version of Scala 2.12 but is hidden behind a compiler flag I think. I hope it will be back ported to 2.11.